# Memory error while trying to display video on tkinter window using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to write a code for a game and I want to display a video in a tkinter window. I'm having some trouble with my code for loading and displaying the video when I use it with my code for the game. But It works fine when I run the code for displaying the video separately. This is the error I get

```
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 2764800 bytes in function 'cv::OutOfMemoryError'
```

Why is this happening?? How can I fix it?? If anyone knows a better way to display the video, that would also be great. Here is the relevant part of my code

```
    def intro(self):
        Game.clear(self)
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture("project_files\\video.mp4")
        width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        def get_frame():
            ret,frame = vid.read()
            if ret :
                return(ret,cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else :
                return(ret,None)    
        def update():
            ret,frame = get_frame()
            if ret :
                img = Image.fromarray(frame)
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
                photo.image=img
                label = Label(root,image=photo)
                label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
                label.image=photo
                root.after(delay,update)
    
        delay = 15
        update()
        Game.qn_call(self,"a",iteration=0)
```

I'm new to tkinter and opencv so pleas keep it simple

Comment: You are creating a brand new Label for each frame of video - but doing nothing with the previous Labels: they're just piling up in memory.  You either need to destroy the previous Label each time, or better yet simply have a single Label, and set its `image` option each time.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the tip. Based on what you said, I modified my code and now it works. I called a function that I had previously defined that clears all the widgets perviously on the screen, every time I called update(). It destroyed all the previous labels, solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. I solved the problem by calling a function that destroys all widgets currently on screen every time update() is called. The relevant parts of the working code is given below

```
    def clear(self):
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        
    def intro(self):
        Game.clear(self)
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture("project_files\\video.mp4")
        width = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
        height = vid.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
        def get_frame():
            ret,frame = vid.read()
            if ret :
                return(ret,cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
            else :
                return(ret,None)
        def update():
            Game.clear(self)    #i added this to delete the labels.
            ret,frame = get_frame()
            print(ret)
            if ret :
                img = Image.fromarray(frame)
                photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
                photo.image=img
                label = Label(root,image=photo)
                label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)
                label.image=photo
            root.after(delay,update)
    
        delay = 15
        update()
        Game.qn_call(self,"a",iteration=0)
```

Comment: Why don't you just create the label once, and update its image inside `update()`?